# Autosize a memo

Tags: delphi, autosize, memo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I make a TMemo size itself to the text it contains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935859/can-i-make-a-tmemo-size-itself-to-the-text-it-contains)

Need to do autosize memo: height and width.

I autosize the height as follows:

```
function TForm1.AutoSizeMemoY(Memo: TMemo): word;
begin
  Canvas.Font := Memo.Font;
  Result := Canvas.TextExtent(Memo.Lines.Strings[0]).cy * Memo.Lines.Count +
    Canvas.TextExtent(Memo.Lines.Strings[0]).cy;
end;
```

But I do not know how to do autosize the width. I have an idea: if the scrollbar is activated, then increase the width until it becomes inactive, but I do not know how to implement that.

Comment: Austosizing can only be achieved in one direction. Either you fix the height and adjust the width or fix the width and adjust the height.

Comment: @SimaWB, I need to, and in width, and height. + font can be different!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the best solution but it works:

```
function GetTextWidth(F: TFont; s: string): integer;
var
  l: TLabel;
begin
  l := TLabel.Create(nil);
  try
    l.Font.Assign(F);
    l.Caption := s;
    l.AutoSize := True;
    result := l.Width + 8;
  finally
    l.Free;
  end;
end;
```

And add following code to the end of Memo1.Onchange event in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/936092/62313)

```
  LineInd := Memo1.Perform(EM_LINEFROMCHAR, Memo1.SelStart, 0);//focused Memo1 line Index
  Wd := GetTextWidth(Memo1.Font, Memo1.Lines[LineInd]);
  //MaxWidthLineInd = index of the line which has the largest width. 
  //Init value of MaxWidthLineInd = 0
  if MaxWidthLineInd = LineInd then 
    Memo1.Width := Wd
  else begin
    if Wd > Memo1.Width then
    begin
      Memo1.Width := Wd;
      MaxWidthLineInd := LineInd;
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: I could not guess to use the label. Thanks!

Comment: Wait, you are going to instantiate `TLabel` to get the text width of a foreign control. Oh my...