# Getting the styled font size of a memo to resize it to its contents' size in Firemonkey on Android

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I've tried multiple things that are all present in answers to this question:
[Can I make a TMemo size itself to the text it contains? - Firemonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21836579/)

1. The top answer with `ContentBounds.Height` works... on Windows. But it does not work on Android. It's always one key press behind. Every time I press a key (be it Enter or 'f' or 'a', etc), the height is fitted to the content that was in the memo before that key was pressed.
2. Filipe.Fonseca's answer straight up doesn't work because there is no `TTextLayout` hiding in the object attachment of a line. Not sure what I'm missing here.
3. `get_memo_height`: This works to the extent that it's not one key press behind. But the `TTextLayout` uses a different Font size:

If I remove the `Size` setting from the `StyledSettings` property of the Memo then `get_memo_height` will produce the right height. When I do that on my phone then the `Font` size (as in `Memo1.Font.Size`, `Memo1.Canvas.Font.Size` and `Memo1.TextSettings.Font.Size`) is reported as 14.

If I add `Size` back in, the `Font` size is still reported as 14. But the `Text` is printed at a size of something like 16 or so.

Does anyone know where this discrepancy is coming from?

Is there a way to get the actual `Font` size the Memo is using while the `StyledSettings` are active?

Comment: For #1, what about using `TThread.ForceQueue()` to delay your reading of the `ContentBounds.Height` until after the key presses are processed?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The delay seems to be gone
But while adding empty lines at the end of the text does increase the height, removing those empty lines doesn't decrease the height. It only snaps to the right height once I remove a visible character.
That's why I still prefer #3, because with that approach I can just add a character to empty lines and the textlayout will thus report the right height.
But I'm currently using a hard font size of 17 for everything so for this and many other things when using styles I'd still like to know how to get a hold of the font size that is actually used.